# Nuxt 3 navigateTo method to open in a new tab

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I want to redirect the user to an external link in a new tab using the navigateTo method. I couldn't find an option to do that similar to having `target="_blank"` in the html tag `<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">` for example

is there is a way to add such a parameter to the [`navigateTo`](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/utils/navigate-to/) method?

```html
<script lang = "ts" setup>
 function onEventTriggered() {
    return navigateTo('https://google.com', {
      external: true,
    })
  } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour you seek is described in the documentation here: https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/navigate-to#navigating-using-open

Use it like this:

```
navigateTo('https://google.com', {
  external: true,
  open: {
    target: "_blank",
  },
});
```

Comment: Does this work on Nuxt version `3.0.0`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you could use a method called `navigateTo` to "open" something in another tab, would be quite non-intuitive and strange because of it's naming.

You can try [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72352446/8816585) tho, to simulate the exact same thing without even needing to add it to the DOM

```html
<script setup>
function openExternal(endpoint) {
  const link = document.createElement('a')
  link.href = endpoint
  link.target = '_blank'
  link.click()
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="openNewTab('https://google.com')">
    Open in new tab
  </button>
</template>
```